# Plugin for an interactive image?

Tags: plugins, images

I'd like to make an interactive image like this one, so when a visitor hovers over that circle, some text dialog pops up. Does anybody know any WordPress plugin that could do that or atleast something close to that? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Image Hotspot by DevVN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/devvn-image-hotspot/) and [Interactive Maps](https://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/) might have what you're looking for!

Comment: Thank you! I will try.

@fuxia - Sorry, didn't know.